# Windows 8.1 Does not Boot for Install

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, iso-image

I took copy of Windows 8.1 pro x64 @ 5GB got it under 4.4 GB removing language packages and keyboards so I could fit it on a DVD. Burned the ISO as an Image to a DVD with ImgBurn and presto no boot from either of my two laptops. One being an Alienware one being Dell Inspiron 1501. I know the ISO was burned as an image on my DVD I can see the files. Where did I go wrong here?

Comment: Try a different tool it's clearly not bootable

Answer (score 0):

For being boot-able there is a special care taken so that the boot loader is properly set and while burning it to a media the format is intact which is necessary for booting. While doing the editing you may have knowingly or unknowingly misplaced the boot loader that's why it is happening.

If you really want to edit an boot-able ISO then first first have a safe copy and then open it with some ISO editing tools that maintain the format for booting.

Or it may be the case that you have just copy the content of C drive and burn it on the DVD that's would not work. because for booting the necessary format will not be there. If you are doing that please use the cloning software. and make it boot-able.